# How can I make user not allow to resize textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have textarea in my website and i want to make user not allow to resize this textarea.
But I use this languages only :
php - html - jquery - javascript

Answer (score 1):

```css
textarea {
   resize:none;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="3"></textarea>
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" style="resize:none;">
    At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. 
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea style="overflow:auto;resize:none" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```